# Cannot import 'GDALRaster' when running docker-comopose local.yml

Tags: django, docker-compose, cookiecutter

I am trying to bring up web application (based on cookiecutter) with docker. My setup consists of LUbuntu 16.04 as virtual machine on top of Win10Pro.

Inside LUbuntu I have Docker, Pyhton3, virtualenv, pip, and docker-compose. When I navigate to project directory first command which I run is

```
docker-compose -f local.yml build
```

Next command:

```
docker-compose -f local.yml up
```

After few success messages from postgres container, I receive this error from django container:

```
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/base.py", line 7, in <module>
django_1    |     from .operations import PostGISOperations
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/operations.py", line 7, in <module>
django_1    |     from django.contrib.gis.gdal import GDALRaster
django_1    | ImportError: cannot import name 'GDALRaster'
```

And another error:

```
django_1    | django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis' isn't an available database backend.
django_1    | Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
django_1    |     'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
django_1    | Error was: cannot import name 'GDALRaster'
beaconpro_django_1 exited with code 1
```

What I expect is that Docker-dev, which is used in local.yml already contains everything what is needed for successful start.

Is there any workaround? Am I missing something?